# How to call an artisan console command with an interaction

Tags: php, laravel, console, command, laravel-artisan

I'm currently creating a php artisan console command in a Laravel 5.1 project, and want to call another console command from my console command. This third party command I want to call does not accept any options or arguments, but rather receives its input via interactive questions.

I know I can call a command with options and arguments like this:

> $this->call('command:name', ['argument' => 'foo', '--option' => 'bar']);

I also know I can call an interactive command without interactions like this from the command line:

> php artisan command:name --no-interaction

---

But how can I answer these interactive questions from within my command?

I would like to do something like the below (pseudo code).

```
$this->call('command:name', [
    'argument' => 'foo', 
    '--option' => 'bar'
], function($console) {
    $console->writeln('Yes'); //answer an interactive question 
    $console-writeln('No'); //answer an interactive question 
    $console->writeln(''); //skip answering an interactive question 
} );
```

---

Of course the above doesn't work, since `$this->call($command, $arguments)` does not accept a third callback parameter.

**How can I answer interactive questions when calling a console command from a console command?**

Comment: I was intrigued by this question. I've played around in a Laravel sandbox for an hour or so to see if I could get this working. I've come to an unfortunate conclusion that it's going to be *alot* of work to implement this functionality. At the moment it's not possible to pipe anything through a call that was made in another call without default values through arguments.

Comment: @DavidBarker I made it work (for now) by adding 5 lines of code in the Symfony class method QuestionHelper@doAsk. I'm currently brainstorming over how I can augment this method without touching the core, thinking about using `runkit_method_redefine()`. Will update this post if/when I succeed. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Still ultra hacky but I can't think or see any other way to achieve what you need without the functionality available in the Symfony components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have another solution, it is to call a symfony command executing 'php artisan' instead of using artisan sub-commands. I think that's better than patching 3rd party code.

Here is a trait which manages this.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
trait ArtisanCommandTrait{
    public function executeArtisanCommand($command, $options){
        $stmt = 'php artisan '. $command . ' ' . $this->prepareOptions($options);

        $process = new Process($stmt);
        $process->run();
        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        return $process->getOutput();
    }
    public function prepareOptions($options){
            $args = [];
            $opts = [];
            $flags = [];
            foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                if(ctype_alpha(substr($key, 0, 1)))
                    $args[] = $value;
                else if(starts_with($key, '--')){
                    $opts[] = $key. (is_null($value) ? '' : '=' . $value) ;
                }
                else if(starts_with($key, '-')){
                    $flags[] = $key;
                }
            }
            return   implode(' ', $args) . ' '
                    .implode(' ', $opts). ' '
                    .implode(' ', $flags);
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to pass any artisan special options such as no-interaction.

```
public function handle(){
    $options = [
            'argument' => $argument,
            '--option' => $options,         // options should be preceded by --
            '-n' => null                    // no-interaction option
        ];
    $command = 'your:command';
    $output = $this->executeArtisanCommand($command, $options);        
    echo $output;
}
```

You can download the trait from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/motia/b7a5a0161305a417ad3bdffa717ec4a9)

Comment: This is better; I'm accepting your answer as the best one

Comment: @PepijnOlivier Except you haven't

Answer (score 1):

**Here's how I did it.**

Beware: this patches the core Symfony class `QuestionHelper@doAsk`, and although this code runs fine for my purposes (I'm currently just making a proof of concept), this code should probably not run in any production environment.
I'm not accepting my own answer yet, would like to know if there's a better way to do this.

The following assumes a Laravel 5.1 installation.

- **First composer-require the [Patchwork](http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork/docs/setup.html) package.** I'm using this to augment the functionality of that Symfony class method.

  > `composer require antecedent/patchwork`
- **Edit `bootstrap/app.php` and add the following right after the application is created.** (Patchwork is not autoloaded)

  ```
  if($app->runningInConsole()) {
      require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/antecedent/patchwork/Patchwork.php');
  };
  ```
- **Add the following two use statements to the top of your console command class**

  > `use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;`
  >
  > `use Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question;`
- **augment/patch `QuestionHelper@doAsk` by using these helper methods on your console command class**

  ```
  public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->patchAskingQuestion();
  }

  /**
   * Patch QuestionHelper@doAsk
   * When a key 'qh-patch-answers' is found in the $_REQUEST superglobal,
   * We assume this is an array which holds the answers for our interactive questions.
   * shift each answer off the array, before answering the corresponding question.
   * When an answer has a NULL value, we will just provide the default answer (= skip question)
   */
  private function patchAskingQuestion() {

      \Patchwork\replace('Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper::doAsk', function(OutputInterface $output, Question $question) {

          $answers = &$_REQUEST['qh-patch-answers'];

          //No predefined answer found? Just call the original method
          if(empty($answers)) {
              return \Patchwork\callOriginal([$output, $question]);
          }

          //using the next predefined answer, or the default if the predefined answer was NULL
          $answer = array_shift($answers);
          return ($answer === null) ? $question->getDefault() : $answer;
      });
  }

  private function setPredefinedAnswers($answers) {
      $_REQUEST['qh-patch-answers'] = $answers;
  }

  private function clearPredefinedAnswers() {
      unset($_REQUEST['qh-patch-answers']);
  }
  ```
- **You can now answer interactive questions like this**

  ```
  public function fire() {
      //predefine the answers to the interactive questions
      $this->setPredefinedAnswers([
          'Yes', //first question will be answered with 'Yes'
          'No', //second question will be answered with 'No'
          null, //third question will be skipped (using the default answer)
          null, //fourth question will be skipped (using the default answer)
      ]);

      //call the interactive command
      $this->call('command:name');

      //clean up, so future calls to QuestionHelper@doAsk will definitely call the original method
      $this->clearPredefinedAnswers();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

With [mpyw/streamable-console: Call interactive artisan command using arbitrary stream](https://github.com/mpyw/streamable-console):

```
$this->usingInputStream("yes\nno\n")->call('command:name');
```